# Make virtual copy of a device

Tags: usb, device, virtual, twain

I have a weird question. I would like to make a virtual copy of a device. In order to test some software I want to make a mirror copy of a particular scanner. Now I know there are some virtual TWAIN scanners out there, but I want Windows to recognise it as a particular brand and type just so I can test the particular software that comes with it.

I.e. I have an HP scanner plugged in, I want to make a mirror copy of it, unplug it and windows will still detect it as plugged in and operating normally so I can open the scanner software and driver. My goal is to make this virtual device stick, even on reboot. Is there any way this can be achieved? I'm happy to load the device data on an USB drive if that works as workaround.

I hope you guys can help me!

Cheers,
Jasper

Answer (score 0):

You probably could do that by writing your own kernel-mode Windows driver that pretends to be a USB hub and pretends that it has a device plugged in to it which is a virtual scanner.  Writing Windows drivers usually involves a lot of arcane C programming and it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you everything you need to do on this type of site.